# Cannot test with rspec controller POST create action( devise and cancan)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, cancan

I am having difficulty getting a rspec test for a controller to pass. I would like to test that the POST create action works.  I am using rails (3.0.3),  cancan (1.4.1), devise (1.1.5),  rspec (2.3.0)

The model is dead simple

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name 
end
```

The controller is standard as well (straight out of scaffolding)

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]
  load_and_authorize_resource
  ...

  def create
    @account = Account.new(params[:account])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @account.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@account, :notice => 'Account was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @account, :status => :created, :location => @account }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @account.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and the rspec test I would like to pass is (excuse the title, perhaps not the most appropriate one)

```
 it "should call create on account when POST create is called" do
   @user = Factory.create(:user)
   @user.admin = true
   @user.save

   sign_in @user #this is an admin
   post :create, :account => {"name" => "Jimmy Johnes"}
   response.should be_success
   sign_out @user

 end
```

Yet all I get is

```
AccountsController get index should call create on account when POST create is called
 Failure/Error: response.should be_success
 expected success? to return true, got false
 # ./spec/controllers/accounts_controller_spec.rb:46
```

Other actions can be tested and do pass (i.e. GET new)

here is the test for GET new

```
it "should allow logged in admin to call new on account controller" do
  @user = Factory.create(:user)
  @user.admin=true
  @user.save

  sign_in @user #this is an admin
  get :new
  response.should be_success
  sign_out @user
end
```

and for completion here is the ability file

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas? My guess is that I am using the wrong rspec expectation, since the code does work (it is just that the test does not perform as desired!)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`response.should be_success` returns true if the response code is in the range 200-299. But the create action redirects, so the response code gets set to 302, thus the failure.

You can test this by using `response.should redirect_to`. Check the output of the standard RSpec controller generator for an example, which might look like this:

```
  it "redirects to the created account" do
    Account.stub(:new) { mock_account(:save => true) }
    post :create, :account => {}
    response.should redirect_to(account_url(mock_account))
  end
```

Comment: zetetic, your answer was excellent. I had to make a few tweeks to get it to pass, but the gist of it was that it should have been a redirect.

Comment: I voted this as the accepted answer since most people seem to find this answer the most useful

Answer (score 3):

The rspec test that got the test to pass was (thanks to zetetic's advice):

```
    it "should call create on account when POST create is called" do
    @user = Factory.create(:user)
    @user.admin = true
    @user.save

    sign_in @user #this is an admin
    account = mock_model(Account, :attributes= => true, :save => true) 
    Account.stub(:new) { account }

    post :create, :account => {}
    response.should redirect_to(account_path(account))
    sign_out @user

end
```